# Autorun windows share mount script after login as root

Tags: mount, login, scripts, root, autostart

I have looked everywhere for a solution that lets me run CIFS automount script after login with around 20 second delay.
What I have tried.
Added the script to visudo:

```
rait ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/rait/Downloads/Testing/mount.sh, /bin/mount
```

After that added the script to ***Startup applications***, but it does not work.
Also I tried adding it to .bash_profile and rc.d. In rc.d it works but that does not run it after login. I need it after login because it will ask people for their AD user and password via GUI.
The script itself looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
MOUNTDIR=Public
DIRNAME=Avalik
DOMAIN=Domain
SERVER=server_adr
SHARE=shares

if [ ! -d ${HOME}/Documents/${DIRNAME} ]; then
    mkdir ${HOME}/Documents/${DIRNAME}
fi

# get the windows username
wUsername=`zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Kasutaja
nimi:"`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

# get the windows password
wPassword=`zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Parool:"
 --hide-text`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

mount -t cifs //$SERVER/$SHARE ${HOME}/Documents/${DIRNAME} -o username=${wUsern
ame},password=${wPassword},domain=${DOMAIN}

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    zenity --info --title="Mount OK!" --text="Mount OK!"
else
    zenity --error --title="Mount Failed!" --text="Mount Failed!"
fi
```

I hope that someone knows how to do it.

**PS:** After I edited the visudo now it asks for root password after I open terminal. So terminal asks me for sudo password when ever I open it after login. Once I remove the line that should run the script in visudo it does not ask for password anymore.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this to sudoers:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /bin/umount
```

And the ***Startup Applications*** command was edited so it was /home/user/script/path/script.sh and it started to work. Also added sudo infront of the mount command in the script as well.

Thanks for you help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a solution for your problem, but you could try to use the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) flag. To do so, make your script owned by root (`chown root:root <filename>`) and then `chmod +s <filename>` it.

Of course you have to be careful which programs you make setuid root, since if the program has a security flaw so its users can make it run arbitrary code, it might be misused to gain full root access.

Regarding the automatic start after login, I think that indeed "Startup Applications" is the place to put it.

Comment: The script has root ownership and I do not want setuid to be honest. I just want it to run in sudo after login and nothing else. 

The script is in Startup Applications and the command to run it is bash /script/dir/

Comment: I even tested ~/.profile but nothing is opening up. The password promt wont open up or anything.

Comment: Fixed it by adding this to sudoers:

    %sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /bin/umount

And the ***Startup Applications*** command was edited so it was /home/user/script/path/script.sh and it started to work. Also added sudo infront of the mount command in the script as well.

:) Thanks for you help guys :)